# Data from postgres mysteriously getting deleted

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I am using cookiecutter-django(https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) for one of my live projects. And from last few days, I am observing the database data randomly getting deleted in parts. I checked logs but I found nothing. I don't know how to approach the issue to resolve it. Will really appreciate any guidance. I am using docker setup with Traefik, Postgres, Redis and celery and django. The code is deployed on a Digital Ocean Bucket. Only I have access to the bucket (Rules out the possibility of any person doing this)

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_traefik: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: fancy_tsunami_production_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: fancy_tsunami_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  traefik:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/traefik/Dockerfile
    image: fancy_tsunami_production_traefik
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - production_traefik:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: fancy_tsunami_production_celeryworker
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: fancy_tsunami_production_celerybeat
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: fancy_tsunami_production_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

Comment: Could yo paste your docker compose?

Comment: Attached docker-compose